# Print sequence of property lists as table

Tags: tables, macros, expl3, latex3, l3seq

I want to define two macros, that together should generate a table for an invoice.

1. Add entries to a sequence. Does not generate any output.

```latex
% \addentry{description}{quantity}{price}
\addentry{Item 1}{5}{4.50}
\addentry{Item 2}{3}{12.00}
```

2. Print all entries as a table, i.e., `\printentries` should expand to

```latex
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrrr}
\toprule
Description & Quantity & Price & Amount \\
\midrule
Item 1 & 5 & 4.50 & 22.50 \\
Item 2 & 3 & 12.00 & 36.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: goal]

### What I tried so far

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {Ne}

\seq_new:N \l__entries_seq
\seq_new:N \l__formatted_entries_seq
\fp_new:N \l__entry_amount_fp
\prop_new:N \l__entry_prop

% \addentry{description}{quantity}{price}
\NewDocumentCommand\addentry{m m m}{
  % Calculate the total amount of this entry by multiplying quantity with price
  \fp_set:Nn \l__entry_amount_fp {#2 * #3}
  % Build the entry
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__entry_prop {
    description={#1},
    quantity={#2},
    price={#3},
    amount={\fp_eval:n \l__entry_amount_fp}
  }
  % Add the entry to the sequence
  \seq_put_right:Ne \l__entries_seq{
    \prop_to_keyval:N \l__entry_prop % Serialize the property list representing the entry
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\printentries{}{
  % Map entries to their row representation (i.e., seperated by `&`) and temporarily store in `\l__formatted_entries_seq`
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__formatted_entries_seq \l__entries_seq {
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__entry_prop {##1} % Deserialize the property list representing the entry

    \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {description} &
    \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {quantity} &
    \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {price} &
    \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {amount}
  }
  
  % Generate the table
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrrr}
  \toprule
  Description & Quantity & Price & Amount \\
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__formatted_entries_seq { \\ } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addentry{Item 1}{5}{4.50}
\addentry{Item 2}{3}{12.00}

\begin{document}
\printentries
\end{document}
```

Strangely enough, this gives me the following output. The 'Description' seems right, but the other columns of 'Item 1' aren't. Why is this wrong?

[image: table output]

### Note for Latex users working with a version of 2021 or older

You might need to add this to your preamble to let my code compile. Add it right after the line of `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

```
%%%% POLYFILL OF THE `\prop_to_keyval:N` MACRO FOR OLD TEX VERSION %%%%
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \prop_to_keyval:N #1
      {
        \__kernel_exp_not:w
          \prop_if_empty:NTF #1
            { {} }
            {
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
              {
                \tex_expanded:D
                  {
                    \__kernel_exp_not:w { \use_none:n }
                    \prop_map_function:NN #1 \@@_to_keyval:nn
                  }
              }
            }
      }
    \cs_new:Npn \@@_to_keyval:nn #1#2
      { , ~ {#1} =~ { \__kernel_exp_not:w {#2} } }
\makeatother
%%%% END POLYFILL %%%%
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the error "LaTeX3 error: A property list was misused." If I proceed by ignoring the error then I get (almost) the output you describe in the question, with Item 2 and the corresponding values listed in both rows. This could be due to my (older) version of expl3, but maybe you get a similar warning or error?

Comment: @Marijn I indeed get a couple of errors (including the misused property list) when I literally run the code from _What I tried so far_. That's because one macro that I use (`\prop_to_keyval:N`) is defined in 2022, but I run a Tex Live version from 2021. When I add the code from _Note for Latex users working with a version of 2021 or older_ right after `\ExplSyntaxOn`, it compiles for me. Does that work for you too?

Comment: If you check what is stored in `\l__entries_seq` after the second `\addentry`, you will see that the amount of the first item is not correct anymore. I have the feeling that you need to expand the keyval entry first before putting it into the sequence. I am unsure, however, if this is the reason to the problem you have. It may be related though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to populate property lists. Just build step by step the body of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g__safron_invoice_body_tl
\fp_new:N \g__safron_invoice_total_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\addentry}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \g__safron_invoice_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:n { #1 } & #2 & #3 & \__safron_invoice_amount:e { \fp_eval:n { #2 * #3 } }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g__safron_invoice_total_fp { #2 * #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printentries}{}
 {
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrrr}
  \toprule
  Description & Quantity & Price & Amount \\
  \midrule
  \tl_use:N \g__safron_invoice_body_tl
  \midrule
  Total &&& \__safron_invoice_amount:e { \fp_use:N \g__safron_invoice_total_fp } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__safron_invoice_amount:n
 {
  \__safron_invoice_amount:w #1 .. \q_stop
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__safron_invoice_amount:w #1 . #2 . #3 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
   { #1.00 }
   { #1.#2 \prg_replicate:nn { 2 - \tl_count:n { #2 } } { 0 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__safron_invoice_amount:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addentry{Item 1}{5}{4.50}
\addentry{Item 2}{3}{12.00}

\printentries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the macro `\__safron_invoice_amount:e`? Wouldn't this work if you directly write `\fp_eval:n { #2 * #3 }`?

Comment: Just tested it. It seems to be working without it.

Comment: @Safron We want to preserve two decimal digits, don't we?

Comment: Aha. I omitted a bit of formatting in my code that already does this, hence why I didn't need that. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

egreg already provided a great and probably much simpler solution. However, as I'm trying to better understand expl3, I was wondering how your original approach can be tweaked so that it outputs the right things.

The problem is, I think, that you need to expand things before you store them as keyval entities in sequences. For example, you need to expand `\fp_eval:n \l__entry_amount_fp`, otherwise you would store this macro sequence in the sequence and it will only expanded when it gets printed where it will always output the last value. (You can check such things using `\seq_show:N` which will print the entries in the sequence to the log.)

Similarly, you need to expand the formatted entries, before adding them to your `\l__formatted_entries_seq` sequence. A quite bulletproof way to do this is to use `\seq_put_right:Nx`. You already used a variant of this in the original defintion for your `\addentry` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__entries_seq
\seq_new:N \l__formatted_entries_seq
\fp_new:N \l__entry_amount_fp
\prop_new:N \l__entry_prop

% \addentry{description}{quantity}{price}
\NewDocumentCommand\addentry{m m m}{
  % Calculate the total amount of this entry by multiplying quantity with price
  \fp_set:Nn \l__entry_amount_fp {#2 * #3}
  % Build the entry
  \prop_put:Nnx \l__entry_prop { description } {#1}
  \prop_put:Nnx \l__entry_prop { quantity } {#2}
  \prop_put:Nnx \l__entry_prop { price } {#3}
  \prop_put:Nnx \l__entry_prop { amount } { \fp_eval:n \l__entry_amount_fp }   % <-- !
  % Add the entry to the sequence
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__entries_seq {
    \prop_to_keyval:N \l__entry_prop % Serialize the property list representing the entry
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\printentries{}{
  % Map entries to their row representation (i.e., seperated by `&`) and temporarily store in `\l__formatted_entries_seq`
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__entries_seq {
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__entry_prop {##1} % Deserialize the property list representing the entry
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__formatted_entries_seq {   % <-- !
      \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {description} &
      \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {quantity} &
      \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {price} &
      \prop_item:Nn \l__entry_prop {amount}
    }
  }
  
  % Generate the table
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrrr}
  \toprule
  Description & Quantity & Price & Amount \\
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__formatted_entries_seq { \\ } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addentry{Item 1}{5}{4.50}
\addentry{Item 2}{3}{12.00}

\begin{document}
\printentries
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is, of course, not as nicely formatted as in egreg's answer ...

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for explaining why my original solution didn't work.

Comment: @Safron To be honest, I am also still learning expl3. Sometimes I cannot really explain why one macro works and the other does not. I assume that although some macros seem to be very similar to one another, in the background they do very different things.